# Safe-core-sdk + fireblocks as signer: Provides different transaction hashes & transaction can be executed in web UI, but not with executeTransaction()

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, exceptions, revert, relay

I'm using an Fireblocks account as a signer ( which uses MPC under the hood ) for my gnosis-safe.

There are two problems that I'm encountering:

1. The transaction hash from the safe-core-sdk and the one that is generated by the Fireblocks SDK are different. Does Fireblocks use a different nonce to calculate the hash or something else?

```
  fireblocks-web3-provider:status Fireblocks transaction 5282c9fd-ea5e-4e2c-b053-591df002e2b4 changed status from SUBMITTED to PENDING_SIGNATURE  +0ms
  fireblocks-web3-provider:status Fireblocks transaction 5282c9fd-ea5e-4e2c-b053-591df002e2b4 changed status from PENDING_SIGNATURE to COMPLETED  +3s
Error: Contract-transaction-hash=0x09ccfb845423e5e788035cb3c5201261c2ad1a1f143eaa28001cc4e8eb648f76 does not match provided contract-tx-hash=0x771a772af4b817c292dca78623a5b2a24fe2e2c67e412b357b4ebd842e1506c8
```

2. I can propose a transaction after I changed to the correct transaction hash, but when I call the 'executeTransaction' function I get `Error: missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string`. I get the same outcome when I want to execute the function with the gelato relayer. However **I can execute it successfully on the safe.global web UI**. Does anyone know what the problem here could be?

```
pendingTxs: [
  {
    safe: '0x4a69381a79faaadb692Dc0E8C37D14fc29dC5418',
    to: '0xd6981777F89aCD65bcD4deEE1EF78f40331AF80c',
    value: '0',
    data: '0x40c10f190000000000000000000000004a69381a79faaadb692dc0e8c37d14fc29dc541800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000acfe18e57e6493b85',
    operation: 0,
    gasToken: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    safeTxGas: 0,
    baseGas: 0,
    gasPrice: '0',
    refundReceiver: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    nonce: 2,
    executionDate: null,
    submissionDate: '2023-10-29T15:11:22.464822Z',
    modified: '2023-10-29T15:11:22.503059Z',
    blockNumber: null,
    transactionHash: null,
    safeTxHash: '0xae9dc9cbbae8639fd1fee7cb0aba7c6e0b54e6abd5e7d8a5c270ece34e239c8f',
    proposer: '0xBc9AD562e2d8ECED7644F3EfF1dA5Fc6E1E6c590',
    executor: null,
    isExecuted: false,
    isSuccessful: null,
    ethGasPrice: null,
    maxFeePerGas: null,
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: null,
    gasUsed: null,
    fee: null,
    origin: '{}',
    dataDecoded: { method: 'mint', parameters: [Array] },
    confirmationsRequired: 1,
    confirmations: [ [Object] ],
    trusted: true,
    signatures: null
  }
]
Error: missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (data="0x", transaction={"from":"0xBc9AD562e2d8ECED7644F3EfF1dA5Fc6E1E6c590","to":"0x3E5c63644E683549055b9Be8653de26E0B4CD36E","data":"0xa0e67e2b","accessList":null}, error={"code":-32000,"payload":{"id":1698592334175162,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_call","params":[{"from":"0xbc9ad562e2d8eced7644f3eff1da5fc6e1e6c590","to":"0x3e5c63644e683549055b9be8653de26e0b4cd36e","data":"0xa0e67e2b"},"latest"]}}, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=providers/5.7.2)
    at Logger.makeError (/Users/max/Code/WaaS/firebloxSafe/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:238:21)
    at Logger.throwError (/Users/max/Code/WaaS/firebloxSafe/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:247:20)
    at checkError (/Users/max/Code/WaaS/firebloxSafe/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:108:16)
    at Web3Provider.<anonymous> (/Users/max/Code/WaaS/firebloxSafe/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:751:47)
    at step (/Users/max/Code/WaaS/firebloxSafe/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.throw (/Users/max/Code/WaaS/firebloxSafe/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:29:53)
    at rejected (/Users/max/Code/WaaS/firebloxSafe/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:21:65)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  reason: 'missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string',
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  data: '0x',
  transaction: {
    from: '0xBc9AD562e2d8ECED7644F3EfF1dA5Fc6E1E6c590',
    to: '0x3E5c63644E683549055b9Be8653de26E0B4CD36E',
    data: '0xa0e67e2b',
    accessList: null
  },
  error: Error: invalid opcode: INVALID
      at /Users/max/Code/WaaS/firebloxSafe/node_modules/@fireblocks/fireblocks-web3-provider/dist/src/provider.js:303:40
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    code: -32000,
    data: undefined,
    payload: {
      id: 1698592334175162,
      jsonrpc: '2.0',
      method: 'eth_call',
      params: [Array]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the repo to the code:

https://github.com/GiraeffleAeffle/firebloxSafe

Thank you!

Comment: It's hard to debug without knowing which part of the code produces the error, but let me try.. On line 149, there's a hardcoded nonce. Have you tried using the actual transaction nonce there?

Comment: Hi @mikheevm, thanks for the advice with the nonce, but that didn't change anything in the outcome, since the transaction can be executed in the web UI of safe. The error is thrown when

`const txResponse = await safeSdk.executeTransaction(safeTransaction)`

inside the test(safeAddress) function is called, but to be able to reproducing it you would need to follow the README.md.

...

Comment: @mikheevm

1. create an account at fireblocks, with the "Editor" role, get the private key and api key and fill the .env

2. In the safe-interaction.js file call the `proposeTransaction` with your safeAddress as argument. Then get the correct hash from the fireblocks output if you get the same error. Then call the function again with the correct transaction hash. Then after that call the `test(safeAddress)` function where the error should be thrown.

Comment: I believe you can sign up for fireblocks only if you go through the demo process with their sales team. Can't do that. You should reach out to them in that case

Comment: Hi @mikheevm, that is only the case for the production environment, but they also have a sandbox environment where anyone can sign up.

https://sandbox.fireblocks.io/v2/

Comment: There's no signup button on the page you shared. Only "No Account? Request a demo"

Comment: @mikheevm oh, I see. I signed up with my company e-mail when I did it and got access right away, but I just tried to do it with a private e-mail and that is not accepted by the form. :/ Then I'll have to ask their team. Thank you for your help!